# How do I Auto-Name Each Subsequent .CSV File of Scraped Date?

Tags: python, csv, filenames, file-io

I'd like to run this code daily and write it automatically to a .csv file. I'm sure whether I'd prefer to have each day be its own file or have each day amend an existing file. If I go with the former, which is what I think I want, I'd like to have each file be auto-named with the date the code was run. Presently I know how to write to a single file that gets over-written each time I run the code. I've done it like this:

```
str1 = "\n".join(data)
outFile = open('sampledata.csv', 'write')
outFile.write(str1)
outFile.close()
```

How do I code this to automatically save to a new .csv file each time and name each subsequent file with the date the code was run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the `datetime` module's `datetime.now()` function to get the current date and time. If you want a specific format use the [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) function to pick the exact format you want. Otherwise, pick a sane default by just using `datetime.datetime.now().date().isoformat()`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2013-11-01'
>>> datetime.datetime.now().date().isoformat()
'2013-11-01'
```

Bringing your code in, the final is this:

```
import datetime
str1 = "\n".join(data)

# Get the current date and time
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now_str = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# Write out to a file for today
outfilename = 'sampledata-{}.csv'.format(now_str)

outFile = open(outfilename, 'write')
outFile.write(str1)
outFile.close()
```

If you want hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds, don't make the call to date (it truncates the timestamp):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
'2013-11-01T21:55:45.465662'
```

However, if you're running this on Windows it won't accept the ':' in the filename. Linux and Macs are ready to go though.

Comment: This makes sense to me, and it works, which is huge for a noob. Thanks. Follow-up question: What if I save two files on the same day? Can I add time to differentiate them, or will the newer one always over-write the older one?

Comment: The newer will overwrite the older one. It's ok to make your format string include hours and minutes too if you like.

Comment: I can just do this, right: now_str = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")

Comment: Yup! That will work, you'll just have to know your own format since it isn't standard.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to have it run a loop or store a state variable so each subsequent run is incremented, i.e.

```
str1 = "\n".join(data)
outFile = open('sampledata'+str(i)+'.csv', 'write')
outFile.write(str1)
outFile.close()
```

In my code, 'i' is just an integer value being kept track of somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting on your filename to include the date or any other data you want. For example, here's how you could append a `YYYY-MM-DD` date onto the end of the file name, just before the extension:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
filename = "sampledata{}.csv".format(today.isoformat())

with open(filename, 'w', newline="") as outFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    # ...
```